# What aria label do I need on an HTML button that changes content using JavaScript and JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

[image]I have a webpage that has some HTML buttons.  Clicking on a button will change the pages text and image content via JavaScript.  The content is loaded from a JSON file.

```
  <div class="dot-buttons role="tablist" aria-label="crew list">
    <button role="tab" class="dot-button" aria-selected="true">Douglas Hurley</button>
    <button role="tab" class="dot-button" aria-selected="false">Mark Shuttlewort</button>
    <button role="tab" class="dot-button" aria-selected="false">Victor Glover</button>
    <button role="tab" class="dot-button" aria-selected="false">Anousheh Ansari</button>
  </div>
```

What I'm confused about is how to markup the ARIA label so the user understands that clicking on the button will change the pages content.

I tried:

```
aria-controls="Tab-1"
```

But this failed my accessibility test since the buttons don't really control other HTML elements. The buttons only change the content within the elements.

How can I set ARIA labels for the buttons so users will understand that clicking on them will change the content?

Comment: I don't think an aria-label is necessary for the buttons as the displayed text (names) is clear. Maybe you should change the aria-label for the div in "select crew members" or something alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code is using the [tab design pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel).  Is that what you want to do?  Do you have something on your page that looks something like this:?

[image]

If so, then the code you have is sufficient.  When the user selects one of the buttons, I presume you toggle [`aria-selected`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-selected) from *"false"* to *"true"* (or vice versa).  When you toggle the value, the screen reader will announce the state change automatically.  That's one of the benefits of using ARIA attributes - it has built in support for notifying assistive technology such as screen readers about changes.

And since you're using [`role="tablist"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#tablist), the combination of the user *hearing* that they have a tablist **and** that a state toggles from "not selected" to "selected" is enough of a hint to the user that something on the page updated when the button was selected.

And if this is the pattern on your page, you *could* have [`aria-controls`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-controls) on your button and it would refer to the ID of the panel it displays, but `aria-controls` doesn't buy you much from assistive technology support.  I think one screen reader (JAWS) does something with it but most of the others don't, so it's not a big deal if you use it or not.  Of course, that's sort of a catch-22.  If screen readers don't support it, then people won't use it, and if people don't use it, there's no incentive for screen readers to support it.  Generally you should use the appropriate ARIA attributes whether there's support for them or not so that you'll be ready when support comes.  The tab design pattern mentioned earlier says that you should use aria-controls.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious.  In my case I'm not sure I can use the aria-controls because I don't have a separate panel that it displays. Clicking the button triggers JS to replace text and images on the same panel.

Comment: I'm guessing then based on your detailed answer that what I have is sufficient.

Comment: Given that you *"don't have a separate panel"* and you *"replace text and images on the same panel"*, that's not really the tab design pattern so your use of `tablist` might not be the right pattern.  Do you have a working example?

Comment: I just have it setup on local so far.  I will upload a photo to give more context.

Comment: Well, let me clarify a bit.  If your example **visually** looks like a tab panel and clicking on the different tabs makes it *appear* like different panels open, then whether you only have one panel that you replace the contents of or if you have multiple panels that you hide/unhide doesn't really matter to the user and a `tablist` **would** be appropriate.